# How can I able to pass the value of field Rating in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My form is

```html
<form id="enquiryBox" method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
  <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <fieldset class="rating">
            <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="5" ><label v-bind:value="5" class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome"></label>
               <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="4" ><label v-bind:value="4" class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good"></label>
                <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="3" ><label v-bind:value="3" class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good"></label>              </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="enquiryEmail" name="enquiryEmail" class="form-control required" title="Email" v-model="enquiryEmail" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" id="enquiryPhone" name="enquiryPhone" class="form-control required" title="Phone" v-model="enquiryPhone" required="required">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Enquiry</label>
          <textarea placeholder="Write your enquiry here" rows="7" id="enquiryDesc" name="enquiryDesc" class="form-control required" title="Desc" v-model="enquiryDesc" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer center-med-res center-sm-res center-xs-res">
    <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn darkGrayButton" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am able to get data other than Rating from the above form. How can I able to pass the rating values.. Now I am getting empty values for rating. For, all other fields I am able to pass the data.

My vue js code

```js
enquiryBox = new Vue({
  el: "#enquiryBox",
  data: {
    rating: '',
    enquiryPhone: '',
    enquiryEmail: '',
    enquiryDesc: '',
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      data['rating'] = this.rating;
      data['enquiryEmail'] = this.enquiryEmail;
      data['enquiryPhone'] = this.enquiryPhone;
      data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/add_review/',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          if (e.status) {
            alert("Review Success")

          } else {
            alert(" Failed")
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

So, how can I able to pass the value of rating. If I select first, I need to pass value 5 otherwise value 4 .. But currently I am not able to pass the data of rating.. I am a beginner.. Please help me to achieve the same??

Comment: Are you able to values other than rating?

Comment: yes I am getting values other than Rating.. But by using above method, I am not able to get the values of rating when I select

Comment: You forgot to add `v-model="rating"` on your radio inputs

Comment: Sir, actually it was not working.. I checked with that too

Comment: @VamsiKrishna can you help me to identify the problem

Comment: @coder you are not binding the `rating` property to your radio inputs. So add `v-model="rating"` to all your radio inputs so the two way data binding works

Comment: @VamsiKrishna actually I have added v-model too, but nothing happens for me

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add `v-model="rating"` to your radio inputs. Try it like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#enquiryBox",
  data: {
    rating: '',
    enquiryPhone: '',
    enquiryEmail: '',
    enquiryDesc: '',
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      data['rating'] = this.rating;
      data['enquiryEmail'] = this.enquiryEmail;
      data['enquiryPhone'] = this.enquiryPhone;
      data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;

      // TODO add your AJAX instead
      console.log(data);

      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<form id="enquiryBox" method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
  <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <fieldset class="rating">
            <input type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="5" v-model="rating" />
            <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="4" v-model="rating" />
            <label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" v-bind:value="3" v-model="rating" />
            <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good"></label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="enquiryEmail" name="enquiryEmail" class="form-control required" title="Email" v-model="enquiryEmail" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" id="enquiryPhone" name="enquiryPhone" class="form-control required" title="Phone" v-model="enquiryPhone" required="required">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Enquiry</label>
          <textarea placeholder="Write your enquiry here" rows="7" id="enquiryDesc" name="enquiryDesc" class="form-control required" title="Desc" v-model="enquiryDesc" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer center-med-res center-sm-res center-xs-res">
    <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn darkGrayButton" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i am not able to get the value of rating

Comment: if you check `console.log(data);` data will contain the value, if the backend doesn't get it then that may be a different problem

Comment: {rating: "", enquiryEmail: "a@gmail.com", enquiryPhone: "0125681172", enquiryDesc: "xfcghjkl;'", p_id: "10", …} this is how i am getting

Comment: run the code snippet, click on one of the three radio buttons so that one of them is selected, input other fields if you want -> click post and check console again :)

Comment: i saw your snippet.. but for me not the the values